# Mongodb Aggregation : select the record of every type that has the highest value in a field

Tags: mongodb

Using the Mongodb Aggregation pipeline (which I am still discovering), how can I select the record of every type that has the highest value in a field.

The result should **include all fields** (variable and not predefined) of the matched rows.

Example data:

```
[
    {_id:1, "type":"a", "price":1, ...},
    {_id:2, "type":"a", "price":2, ...},
    {_id:3, "type":"b", "price":3, ...},
    {_id:4, "type":"b", "price":4, ...},
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    {_id:2, "type":"a", "price":2, ...},
    {_id:4, "type":"b", "price":4, ...},
]
```

I thought about

1. use `$sort` then a `$limit` of 1. But how to apply the limit to each type and not the entire set ?
2. use a `$match` with some sort of "where max" condition if it exists ?
3. use `$group` with `$max` or `$first` but this does not include all fields

How to order or nest the operations to acheive the desired result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the query below:

```
db.yourDb.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $sort: {
                "price": -1
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": "$type",
                "document": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                "newRoot": "$document"
            }
        },

    ]

);
```

It should return the following results:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(2), 
    "type" : "a", 
    "price" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(4), 
    "type" : "b", 
    "price" : NumberInt(4)
}
```

Comment: What if I do not know the other fields to include but I want all of them ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your question. I have edited my answer. Remember that `$replaceRoot` is available since Mongo 3.4.